# How can I conditionally add the filter option_home?

Tags: filters

I've disabled the in-built sitemap in WordPress with `add_filter( 'wp_sitemaps_enabled', '__return_false' );` I'd like to check if this is set and if yes, to conditionally load `add_filter( 'option_home'`.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that if `wp_sitemaps_enabled` has a filter and it has that because we wanted to set it to false, otherwise it defaults to true for public sites. So I would just use and check whether it is filtered or not:

```
add_filter( 'wp_sitemaps_enabled', '__return_false' );

if (has_filter( 'wp_sitemaps_enabled') === true) {

    add_filter('option_home', 'any_callback_function');

} else {

    // echo "the Sitemap is not filtered";

}
```

Other useful approach could be if you use the WP_Sitemaps object to check the status of sitemaps:

```
add_filter( 'wp_sitemaps_enabled', '__return_false' );

$thisSiteMap = new WP_Sitemaps();

$site_map_status = $thisSiteMap->sitemaps_enabled(); 

// var_dump($site_map_status); // just to check the value

if ($site_map_status === false) { // which means sitemaps are filtered/not available

    echo "sitemaps are turned off";
    add_filter('option_home', 'my_uri_function'); // any custom callback function
}

// example callback function
function my_uri_function() {

    $myurl =  get_site_url() . '/shop';

    return $myurl;
}
```

Comment: thanks. I'm assuming that `whatever` in `add_filter('option_home', 'whatever');`  can call the intended function?

Comment: @Ryan - I mean, I should have used a better placeholder for that, like `’any_filter_function’`, just to be clearer on that.

Comment: @Ryan - I added a sample callback function to my second example just to make sure...